# Error when attempting to save xlsx file to S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, xlsxwriter

Attempting to save an xlsx file to an s3 bucket using the following method:

```
import io
import pronounceable
import boto3
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

bucket = 'your-s3-bucketname'
filepath = 'path/to/your/file.format'
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]})

with io.BytesIO() as output:
    with pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, 'sheet_name')
    data = output.getvalue()
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.Bucket(bucket).put_object(Key=filepath, Body=data)
```

However this results in the following error:

```
No module named 'xlsxwriter': ModuleNotFoundError
```

I have tried to install xlsxwriter as a layer to my lamdbda function (as I have with other packages/modules) but it seems I am already using the allocated amount of file space for layers.

```
Layers consume more than the available size of 262144000 bytes
```

***QUESTION***

Is there anyway I export the file without xlsxwriter or otherwise increase the allocated space for layers so that I can add it?

Comment: How come pandas and xmlwriter take 260MB? But anyway, you can use lambda container with **10 GB** of space.

Comment: @Marcin Thank you. Forgot to mention other layer, pronounceable, which uses NLTK corpora and thus likely consumes a large part of the allowance. Will look into containerising although not the preferred option.

Comment: Do you use `xlsxwriter`? What about default xlsx engine of pandas? Your code shows that you just import `xlsxwriter` without using it.

Comment: @Marcin They're using `ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')`, which indeed requires the xlsxwriter module to operate correctly.